# Using Linux awk command in php

Tags: php, html, linux

Good Day All
I'm having a problem getting this command to work on button press
I need to search through a file and output the results in comma delimited text.
PHP doesnt seem to like the curly brackets so as far as I could read I need to use exec(), but to no avail as the error I recieve is "syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'"
I'm still new to php so sorry if the answer is obvious!
Any info will be helpful, Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Linux Command Test</h1>

<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
     $output = exec('grep -i hello test.txt | awk -v OFS=, '{\$1=\$1;print}' > newtest.txt');
     echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
  }
 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you just write the equivalent code directly in PHP, instead of shelling out to awk?

Comment: I was hoping to do that, but seeing as my google skills aren't as good as I hoped, i'm falling back on my linux experience.

Comment: OK, then post your PHP script that tries to run the shell commands, not just the shell commands by themselves.

Comment: Sorry for that, code posted. Thanks, just thought someone has had the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = exec('grep -i hello test.txt | awk -v OFS=, '{\$1=\$1;print}' > newtest.txt');
```

should be:

```
$output = exec('awk -v OFS=, \'/hello/i {$1=$1;print}\' test.txt > newtest.txt');
```

You need to escape the quotes, otherwise they delimit the PHP string. You don't need to escape `$` inside single-quoted strings in PHP. You shouldn't redirect the `awk` output to a file if you want to capture it in a PHP variable.

And there's no need to pipe `grep` to `awk`, since `awk` has built-in pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but now the whole file is comma delimited, the reason I use grep is to filter out all lines with the word hello in it. Thanks

Comment: Your `grep` command processes ONLY the lines with hello in it. If you wanted to filter them out it should be `grep -v`. And the whole point of `OFS=,` is to make it comma-delimited.

Comment: I put back the output redirection. `exec()` only returns the last line of the output, if you want to capture everything in a PHP variable, you have to pass the optional second argument, which is a variable containing an array that will be filled in with each line of the output.

Comment: Thanks for the info, for some reason I've been using grep to output to files for a while, again thanks for the input. Never to old to learn!!!

Comment: Thanks again, with a little coding and a lot of head banging I got to work!

Answer (score 3):

try escaping the $

```
grep -i hello test.txt | awk -v OFS=, '{\$1=\$1;print}' > newtest.txt
```

Comment: I have tried escaping but then I get other errors, I have tried excludeshellargs(), and excludeshellcmd(), still same error. After escaping the error is syntax error, " unexpected '{' ". Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of functions you can use in PHP to invoke external applications, `exec()`, `system()` etc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php but mind that it's up to administrator to let you use them. On most shared hostings these functions are disabled

Comment: That doesn't seem to be his problem. He seems to be having a problem with string interpolation.